# How to get to know when qtconcurrent actually run

Tags: qtconcurrent

As mentioned in doc for QtConcurrent::run:

> Note that the function may not run immediately; the function will only be run when a thread is available.

So here is a question: how to handle job running?
QFutureWatcher signal start is not suitable because

> This signal is emitted when this QFutureWatcher starts watching the future set with setFuture().